# Need to call the same function twice but am getting 'invalid redeclaration' error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, redeclaration

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textfield: UITextField) -> Bool{
        p1s1TextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textfield: UITextField)-> Bool{
        p2s1TextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
}
```

So this is the code I need to write, the only difference being that they affect two different text fields. I understand I need to change the sender in order to avoid the redeclaration error but am unsure what to change it to.

Comment: You need to read the parameter of that method (`textField`). You could do (`textField.resignFirstResponder()`). In case of different use case (`if (textField == p1s1TextField){doSomethingSpecifictops1s1}else{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use one of them and the `parameter textfield` is your current `textfield`.

So:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textfield: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textfield.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to use delegate method according to different Text-fields.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textfield: UITextField) -> Bool{
    if textfield == p1s1TextField {
        p1s1TextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }else if textfield == p2s1TextField {
        p2s1TextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
        return true
}
```